# How to access a shared native library from multiplethreads in java?

Tags: java, linux, shared-libraries, native

I have a native shared library implemented in C which I'm invoking through java JNI, now I have to access the native library in parallel in multiple java threads the problem is the threads are started after serialization and are independent of one other. 
so when i try to load the library in all the threads in parallel i see "java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError".

i have doubt in how the shared library works in this case and is it possible to access the shared library in multiple threads at the same time? i know that my shared library is thread safe means it doesn't using any global variables.

I'm running the program in Linux box.

Thanks.

Comment: Anybody please help!

Comment: We just need to load the JNI library once, and it will be available to all threads, just like any library would be in C. Are you using a custom class loader from within a container or something by any chance?

Comment: Thanks Samuel for reply! I'm using URLClassLoader, the problem is that all the objects are serialized and runs on the machine hence there is no common class to load it.

Comment: It sounds like what you are trying to do is not possible: http://stackoverflow.com/a/16189410/523744 You're going to need to find a way to share the class loaders across your code.